# How to detect if a Windows application is secretly taking print screen and sending to a remote server?

Tags: windows, spyware

I recently installed a trading application from an apparently legitimate source. It is connected to a remote server and run in administrator mode. I wounder if it does malicious activities without our knowledge, e.g. recording the content of the screen and sending it to the remote server.

Just like keylogger or some sort, is it possible to detect if print screen command is triggered? Or is there some other way to find out if the program is spying on us?

Comment: Could you give us a little bit more context? Are you a system administrator with full access to the system? Or are you an application developer that want to know if people are taking screenshots of your application? Or any other scenario?

Comment: For most spyware, antivirus is your best bet. Some antivirus let you enable stringent check (with high false positive rate) that may uncover new spyware.

Comment: If this application is something like back orifice or a remote desktop connection then they could just screenshot the remote screen.

Comment: +Ricardo Reimao thanks for replies. sorry for lack of context. It is a trading application and apparently from a legitimate source and is connected to a remote server. It is run in administrator mode. I wonder if it does the malicious activities without our knowing.

Comment: detecting traffic is trivial, and your best bet for this particular threat

Comment: have you done any research? I'm getting a lot of relevant hits for "windows detect print screen"

Comment: thanks schroeder, I used your keyword and found what I'm looking for

Comment: If it wants to be run as admin, then it is doing something dodgy. As there is probably (almost certainly) no need for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found answer on StackOverflow and build a Global Interceptor.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application

Here is my working code for C# VS2005:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Interceptor
{
    class GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs : HandledEventArgs
    {
        private GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState keyboardState;
        private GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent keyboardData;

        public GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState KeyboardState
        {
            get { return keyboardState; }
            set { this.keyboardState = value; }
        }
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent KeyboardData {
            get { return keyboardData; }
            set { this.keyboardData = value; }
        }

        public GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(
            GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent keyboardData,
            GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState keyboardState)
        {
            KeyboardData = keyboardData;
            KeyboardState = keyboardState;
        }
    }

    //Based on https://gist.github.com/Stasonix
    class GlobalKeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        public event EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> KeyboardPressed;

        public GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // we must keep alive _hookProc, because GC is not aware about SetWindowsHookEx behaviour.

            _user32LibraryHandle = LoadLibrary("User32");
            if (_user32LibraryHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, "Failed to load library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }



            _windowsHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, _user32LibraryHandle, 0);
            if (_windowsHookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, "Failed to adjust keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // because we can unhook only in the same thread, not in garbage collector thread
                if (_windowsHookHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_windowsHookHandle))
                    {
                        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, "Failed to remove keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                    }
                    _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                    // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
                    _hookProc -= LowLevelKeyboardProc;
                }
            }

            if (_user32LibraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (!FreeLibrary(_user32LibraryHandle)) // reduces reference to library by 1.
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, "Failed to unload library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                }
                _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private IntPtr _windowsHookHandle;
        private IntPtr _user32LibraryHandle;
        private HookProc _hookProc;

        delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        /// <summary>
        /// The SetWindowsHookEx function installs an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain.
        /// You would install a hook procedure to monitor the system for certain types of events. These events are
        /// associated either with a specific thread or with all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">hook type</param>
        /// <param name="lpfn">hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="hMod">handle to application instance</param>
        /// <param name="dwThreadId">thread identifier</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle to the hook procedure.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// The UnhookWindowsHookEx function removes a hook procedure installed in a hook chain by the SetWindowsHookEx function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hhk">handle to hook procedure</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

        /// <summary>
        /// The CallNextHookEx function passes the hook information to the next hook procedure in the current hook chain.
        /// A hook procedure can call this function either before or after processing the hook information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHook">handle to current hook</param>
        /// <param name="code">hook code passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// A virtual-key code. The code must be a value in the range 1 to 254.
            /// </summary>
            public int VirtualCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// A hardware scan code for the key. 
            /// </summary>
            public int HardwareScanCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// The extended-key flag, event-injected Flags, context code, and transition-state flag. This member is specified as follows. An application can use the following values to test the keystroke Flags. Testing LLKHF_INJECTED (bit 4) will tell you whether the event was injected. If it was, then testing LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED (bit 1) will tell you whether or not the event was injected from a process running at lower integrity level.
            /// </summary>
            public int Flags;

            /// <summary>
            /// The time stamp stamp for this message, equivalent to what GetMessageTime would return for this message.
            /// </summary>
            public int TimeStamp;

            /// <summary>
            /// Additional information associated with the message. 
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr AdditionalInformation;
        }

        public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        //const int HC_ACTION = 0;

        public enum KeyboardState
        {
            KeyDown = 0x0100,
            KeyUp = 0x0101,
            SysKeyDown = 0x0104,
            SysKeyUp = 0x0105
        }

        public const int VkSnapshot = 0x2c;
        //const int VkLwin = 0x5b;
        //const int VkRwin = 0x5c;
        //const int VkTab = 0x09;
        //const int VkEscape = 0x18;
        //const int VkControl = 0x11;
        const int KfAltdown = 0x2000;
        public const int LlkhfAltdown = (KfAltdown >> 8);

        public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            bool fEatKeyStroke = false;

            int wparamTyped = wParam.ToInt32();
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KeyboardState), wparamTyped))
            {
                object o = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent));
                LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent p = (LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent)o;

                GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs eventArguments = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(p, (KeyboardState)wparamTyped);

                EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> handler = KeyboardPressed;
                handler.Invoke(this, eventArguments);

                fEatKeyStroke = eventArguments.Handled;
            }

            return fEatKeyStroke ? (IntPtr)1 : CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Interceptor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetupKeyboardHooks();
        }

        private GlobalKeyboardHook _globalKeyboardHook;

        public void SetupKeyboardHooks()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
            _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
        }

        private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode);

            if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode != GlobalKeyboardHook.VkSnapshot)
                return;

            // seems, not needed in the life.
            //if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.SysKeyDown &&
            //    e.KeyboardData.Flags == GlobalKeyboardHook.LlkhfAltdown)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Alt + Print Screen");
            //    e.Handled = true;
            //}
            //else

            if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.KeyDown)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Print Screen");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook.Dispose();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see three viable paths to figure out if the app is spying on you:

- As you suggest, try to hook into Windows to figure out if a print screen command is issues. This will not catch everything though - maybe it is figuring out the content of the screen without using any Windows API, or maybe it spies on you by some other method than looking at the screen. How to do this is more of a Windows question than a security question, so I will not answer it here. (And frankly, I have no idea how to do it.)
- Look at the traffic the program is sending. This can be done with a program like Wireshark. I would run it on an other machine on the network, though, since a really evil program might be smart enough to figure out that it is being monitored if you run it on the same computer.
- Decompile the program and reverse engineer it. This requires a lot of time and skill, but it could be argued that it would give you the best answer.

None of these methods are completely failsafe, and I am tempted to say that if you don't think you can trust the people selling you the program maybe you should not run it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure the Windows firewall to notify you](https://superuser.com/questions/217551/how-can-i-configure-the-windows-7-firewall-to-prompt-me-on-outbound-traffic) when unfamiliar outbound traffic is detected.

Warning: Windows may create a lot of normal outbound traffic that you are not familiar with, so be careful what you block!

Comment: A malicious program with Administrative rights can thumb its nose at other code running on the same box. How would Windows Firewall be an exception?

Comment: If Windows firewall is disabled you get an alert in message center.  If ports are re-enabled you can tell from the firewall's UI.  But you are right, an omnipotent program running locally could theoretically overcome any and all solutions, short of hooking up an external device to the network.